# Optimizing .hex file size for embedded programming

Tags: c++, optimization, embedded, hex, neural-network

Intended Platform: Teensy 3.1 (microcontroller)

IDE: CodeBlocks

Current Toolchain: GNU

Current .cpp file size: ~ 3kb

Current .hex file size: ~ 950kb

This .hex file size seems unreasonably large considering the corresponding .cpp is only ~ 3kb, is this normal? I understand that the .hex will be larger, but 300x larger? Geez.

The program compiles and runs as intended on my computer, so no issues there.

I have almost no embedded programming experience outside loading a few simple sketches onto an UNO using the Arduino IDE, so any pointers on streamlining my program would be greatly appreciated. Can this problem be tackled in the C++ code or is there another avenue/toolchain I can implement for tackling this problem?

Code for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

double hidden_out = 0;
double netOutput = 0;
double bias2_out = 0;
double delta1 = 0;
double delta2 = 0;
double delta3 = 0;
double delta4 = 0;
double delta5 = 0;
double bias = 1;
double val = 0;

vector<double> neuron1_out;
vector<double> neuron2_out;
vector<double> neuron3_out;
vector<double> neuron4_out;
vector<double> weightVals;
vector<double> bias1_out;
vector<double> topology;
vector<double> inputs;

neuron1_out.clear();
neuron2_out.clear();
neuron3_out.clear();
neuron4_out.clear();
weightVals.clear();
bias1_out.clear();
topology.clear();
inputs.clear();

topology.push_back(4);
topology.push_back(8);
topology.push_back(1);

inputs.push_back(1);
inputs.push_back(0);
inputs.push_back(0);
inputs.push_back(1);

ifstream read("weights.txt");

while(read >> val) {

    weightVals.push_back(val);

};

for(int i = 0; i < topology.at(1); ++i) {

    int j = i + topology.at(1);
    int k = j + topology.at(1);
    int m = k + topology.at(1);
    int n = m + topology.at(1);

    delta1 = (inputs.at(0) * weightVals.at(i));
    neuron1_out.push_back(delta1);

    delta2 = (inputs.at(1) * weightVals.at(j));
    neuron2_out.push_back(delta2);

    delta3 = (inputs.at(2) * weightVals.at(k));
    neuron3_out.push_back(delta3);

    delta4 = (inputs.at(3) * weightVals.at(m));
    neuron4_out.push_back(delta4);

    delta5 = (bias * weightVals.at(n));
    bias1_out.push_back(delta5);

}

for(unsigned i = 0; i < topology.at(1); ++i) {

    hidden_out += (weightVals.at(40 + i) * tanh(neuron1_out.at(i) + neuron2_out.at(i) +
                                            neuron3_out.at(i) + neuron4_out.at(i) + bias1_out.at(i)));

}

bias2_out = (bias * weightVals.back());

netOutput = tanh(hidden_out + bias2_out);

cout << "The output of this network is: " << netOutput << endl;

return 0;

}
```

A bit of background:

** This portion is non-critical to answering my question **

This file is a massively stripped down version of a neural network (NN) program I intend to load onto the Teensy. The basic idea is that the original neural network program is much too large and complex for our MC to handle in a timely manner. By extracting the weights of the computer based NN and importing them to the program above, we effectively cut the unnecessary portions of the NN related to training and error handling and maintain only the 'feed forward' functionality. Unfortunately, this only reduced my overall .hex file size from ~ 1150kb to ~ 950kb.

Comment: See whether getting rid of `#include <iostream>` and `#include <fstream>` and using `printf` for your output and `fscanf` for file reading has a significant effect.

Comment: Did you even check the size of the generated binay? Just have a look at the map file, you might be surprised. Just think: you use features of the STL, which is known to bloat your code.

Comment: There is no microcontroller called "teensy", that some board which apparently comes with MK20DX256VMC7, which is a Freescale ARM Cortex M4 with 256kb flash. And yeah it is a microcontroller, not a PC.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, understand that the hex file format is an ascii text representation of the binary image. Each hex record contains two characters per byte of binary, plus record type, location, length and checksum data; as such the actual binary image size will be less than half the hex file size.

Your toolchain will have created (or at least has the option to create) a linker map file that will show the actual size and all the components that constitute the image.

Source file size is no indicator of program size. In your case you have included STL and iostream library code that is very memory hungry, and best avoided on vert constrained targets.

Answer (score 1):

HEX file is anout 3 times the size of the actual program it represents.

My guess is the most of it is the floating point emulation library and C++ support. You can look at the map file to find out what is taking space.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to compile this code for Cortex-M3 with GCC (latest version from https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)

Because in bare-metal system I dont have support for iostream and filestream, i commented out `ifstream read` and `cout << ...`.

Compiled code take about 9.5kbytes (hex-file size - 36k).

Try to remove `ifstream` (do you have fully functional file system on your board?). For example, read values from static const array.